# How do you show the scale bar in MapBox for iOS?

Tags: ios, mapbox

Would like to show a scale bar on my map. How can I do this? Is it not ready yet? here is my code:

```
    let hi = mapView.scaleBar
    hi.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (mapView.frame.size.height / 2), width: 100, height: 50)
    mapView.addSubview(hi)
```

This code is in my viewDidLoad. Map is working great, just no scale bar.

Comment: Question is so vague..

Comment: Made the title better and clarified. Hopefully now its a fair question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift:

```
mapView.scaleBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: Does this actually work for you? Should it be `mapView.scaleBar.hidden = NO`?